# Bower register for bitbucket private repo

Tags: bower, bower-register

How to register bower private repo on bitbucket if its possible? I try next

```
bower register example git@bitbucket.org:devs_example/example-code.git
```

but still error `EINVFORMAT Invalid URL format`